# Calendar seconds are not increasing in while loop

Tags: java, calendar

I am trying to make the while loop stop after 5 seconds and a half (5.5) so I am using the Calendar library to get the current second of the minute and then increment 5.5 onto it. After that process it loops round waiting for the current time to be equal to the saved variable

I realised that the seconds are NOT increasing... why is that?

Code:

```
package me.fangs.td;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        double timeout = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND) + 5.5;
        while((double) calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND) < timeout) {
            System.out.println((double) calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND));
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Because `Calendar` doesn't change the time unless you change its time. But anyway, this is probably not what you intend to use, as this is seconds within the minute, so if you start it at, say, 57 seconds past a minute, you'll never get to 62.5 seconds past a minute.

Comment: `Calendar` is a snapshot, not a "clock".  Seriously though, you shouldn't be using it, you should be making using of the newer and improved date/time API introduced in Java 8

Comment: But if I restart the file the time changes again, how can I make it dynamically update

Comment: Ok, then which lib is that?

Comment: `calendar.setTime(new Date())`.

Comment: [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html).

Comment: [Date and Time Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/datetime.html)

Comment: @PhantomFangs Is there any particular reason why you are just not using `Thread.sleep(5500)`?

Comment: Because that sleeps for 5.5 seconds which isn't what I'm looking for.

Comment: @PhantomFangs But your `while` loop is doing exactly that, it is pausing the thread for 5.5 seconds.

Comment: No, my code isn't even working. The intended use is to stop the loop after 5.5 seconds have passed, not to pause the entire code for 5.5 seconds

Comment: FYI, the terrible `Calendar` class was supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes. Never use `Calendar`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't use the Calender library at all, instead I'd use `System.currentTimeMillis()`

Here's a while loop which terminates after 5.5 seconds:

```
long end = System.currentTimeMillis() + 5500;
while (System.currentTimeMillis() < end) {
  //Do something
}
//Exit after 5.5 seconds
```

This version has the advantage, that you can change the end time while the loop is running, changing the time the loop will run.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of implementing my own, I would prefer / use [`Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) which is *a facility for threads to schedule tasks for future execution in a background thread.* Like,

```
Timer t = new Timer();
TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Five seconds");
    }
};
t.schedule(task, TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(5) + 500); // 5.5 seconds.
```

Comment: @PhantomFangs Why would you want to? Now this sounds like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/243725).

Comment: I suppose I'll kinda have to try it

Comment: Yes, @PhantomFangs, this works as it stands. It may be implemented using a thread, but I don’t think you would have to worry about that.

Answer (score 1):

## java.time

The [Answer by VoroX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56419812/642706) is correct. But using java.time makes it more elegant and self-documenting.

We call `Instant.now` each time through the loop to capture the new current time. The date-time objects are not auto-updating. They are a snapshot of that moment, frozen. Ask in each case when you want the current time.

```
Duration wait = Duration.ofSeconds( 5 ).plusMillis( 500 ) ;  // 5.5 seconds.
Instant now = Instant.now() ;
Instant stop = now.plus( d ) ;

while( Instant.now().isBefore( stop ) ) 
{
   // Do some task. 
}
```

In real work I would also add a check that `stop.isAfter( start )` in case the Duration ever got edited to be negative.